# On iOS, is there a way to directly alter or draw to CGImage instead of drawing to Graphics Context and then convert the whole thing?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d, cgimage

If we already have a Bitmap Graphics Context, and we converted this context to a `CGImage`.  Now we want to add a single dot to the `CGImage`.  Can we alter the `CGImage` directly, instead draw a single dot to the graphics context and covert the whole context once again to a `CGImage`?

The idea is that `CGImage` is also a structure, so if we can alter some data in the structure, that should somehow be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGImages are immutable. They cannot be changed after they are created.

> If we already have a Bitmap Graphics Context, and we converted this context to a CGImage

[`CGBitmapContextCreateImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000947-CH1g-BAJDJIFF) doesn't "convert" a context to an image -- it effectively takes a snapshot of the current state of the context.

You can draw more things in the original context. (The first CGImage will not be affected.) Then call `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` again, to get a new image with the new drawing in it.

Comment: I see... maybe another reason is that the CGImage is like a PNG or JPG... we cannot easily alter its data to add a dot, not like bitmap. yes, my sense of "convert" is like converting a BMP file to a JPG file -- the original BMP can still be used, but just that a new JPG file is created